# Ubuntu Gnome freezes/can't click on anything in VirtualBox full screen mode

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, fullscreen

So if I maximize/full screen my Ubuntu Gnome VM it "freezes", I can't click on anything and hides desktop icons+dock.

It however works just fine if I "un-maximize" it and use it on a smaller window.

This just happens with Ubuntu Gnome, while "normal ubuntu" fully works in full screen, I'm also kinda new to this so it might be a stupid thing, anyone knows what's up? Thanks

Comment: Can you try to install the "Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions" and turn off "Enable 3D Acceleration" ? Try them one at a time with a VM restart after each. Then both together.

Comment: @Yukon, please accept **jwcooper**'s answer if it helped you solve the problem. And don't forget to delete your answer since it should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Install the "Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions" and turn off "Enable 3D Acceleration". Try them one at a time with a VM restart after each. Then both together if you don't see any results. Here is a link on how to install the guest additions on Ubuntu:[Install Virtual box Guest Additions](https://www.tecmint.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

@jwcooper's solution worked! Just simply needed to install guest additions (even if "normal ubuntu" worked anyway), thanks!

Comment: Nice. I'll make it an answer below so you can accept it as correct.